# Datagridview programmatically select multiple rows and sum up values in one column

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
Column1        Column 2
Payment 2001   $45.9
Refund 2002    $56.8 
Refund 2003    $67.9
Payment 2004   $88.0
Payment 2006   $39.9
```

Hi. I have a `DataGridView` with two columns. One column is a  text description and the other column is the actual values. I want to sum up just the payment values and display the  decimal sum to a `TextBox` by button click. My payment sum from above is $173.8 and this is what I want to display in my `TextBox`. I've managed to cobble together enough code to select my initial payment value but I've been stuck since. :)

Any help will be appreciated. My code so far:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; index++)
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[index];
        if (cell.Value == DBNull.Value || cell.Value == null)
            continue;
        if (cell.Value.ToString().Contains("Payment"))
        {
            DataGridViewCell next = row.Cells[index + 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Declare a variable before your loops:

```
decimal sum = 0m;
```

Then, using your same code, within your loops just parse out the amounts (with the appropriate `CultureInfo`) and add them up as you loop:

```
sum += Decimal.Parse(next.Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency, myCultureInfo);
```

---

**Example**

I created the following test to show how it should parse out the same for any culture. <strike>(I couldn't test GHS as I couldn't find the correlating `CultureInfo` for it, but I still tested another multi-character one for demo purposes.)</strike> For GHS, you can create a custom culture.  A fully customized example can be seen below, though for GHS you will probably only need change the `custom.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol` property.

```
decimal amount = 1234.56m;

CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo gb = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
CultureInfo by = new CultureInfo("be-BY");
                                                            // Values for...
CultureInfo custom = (CultureInfo)us.Clone();               // USD      GHS
custom.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 2;              // 2        2
custom.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = " DECIMAL "; // "."      "."
custom.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = " GROUP ";     // ","      ","
custom.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSizes = new int[] { 2 };   // { 3 }    { 3 }
custom.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 0;            // 0        0
custom.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = 0;            // 0        0
custom.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "SYMBOL ";             // "$"      "₵" or "GH₵" ?

NumberFormatInfo nf1 = us.NumberFormat;
NumberFormatInfo nf2 = gb.NumberFormat;
NumberFormatInfo nf3 = by.NumberFormat;
NumberFormatInfo nf4 = custom.NumberFormat;

string s1 = amount.ToString("c", nf1);
string s2 = amount.ToString("c", nf2);
string s3 = amount.ToString("c", nf3);
string s4 = amount.ToString("c", nf4);

Console.WriteLine(s1);    // $1,234.56
Console.WriteLine(s2);    // £1,234.56
Console.WriteLine(s3);    // 1 234,56 Br
Console.WriteLine(s4);    // SYMBOL 12 GROUP 34 DECIMAL 56

decimal d1 = Decimal.Parse(s1, NumberStyles.Currency, us);
decimal d2 = Decimal.Parse(s2, NumberStyles.Currency, gb);
decimal d3 = Decimal.Parse(s3, NumberStyles.Currency, by);
decimal d4 = Decimal.Parse(s4, NumberStyles.Currency, custom);

Console.WriteLine(d1);    // 1234.56
Console.WriteLine(d2);    // 1234.56
Console.WriteLine(d3);    // 1234.56
Console.WriteLine(d4);    // 1234.56
```

Comment: Thanks OhBeWise. That worked well for me. However i noticed if i change the dollar sign to another currency say GBP or GHS then i get a too many characters in character literal error. i tried to use " " instead of ' ' but no luck. I got an implicit conversion error

Comment: @Gonja Good catch.  That method will fail for numerous other currency types since the currency symbol may be multiple characters.  I did more research based off this additional requirement and found a better way to parse out the numeric amounts.  I also found that it's better to convert to `decimal` instead of `double`.  I've updated my answer to reflect these changes.

Comment: Appreciate the help @ OhBeWise. Your example was very helpful. I'm currently working with the GHS currency so i did a little research myself and came up with no cultreinfo for it. I'm trying to use invariant culture to solve the problem but i'm getting an input string was not in a correct format error from the line below. Any ideas?                                      sum += Decimal.Parse(next.Value.ToString(),NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: @Gonja You are getting that error because `next.Value.ToString()` probably doesn't look like this: `¤1,234.56`, which was my output when I used an `InvariantCulture`. Regardless, I believe using a customized [NumberFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.numberformat(v=vs.110).aspx) will work. I've updated my example to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

@OhBeWise That worked flawlessly. Really appreciate the help. Thank you for your patience. Full code below

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   decimal amount = 0;

   CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
   CultureInfo custom = (CultureInfo)us.Clone();
   custom.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "GHS ";


   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
   {
       for (int index = 0; index < dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; index++)
       {
           DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[index];
           if (cell.Value == DBNull.Value || cell.Value == null)
               continue;
           if (cell.Value.ToString().Contains("Payment"))
           {
               DataGridViewCell next = row.Cells[index + 1];
               string s4 = next.Value.ToString();
               amount+= Decimal.Parse(s4, NumberStyles.Currency, custom);

                    textBox22.Text = amount.ToString();
               }



           }


       }
```